# How to do socks5 port forward with ssh?

Tags: ssh

I typically do a `ssh -L 0.0.0.0:1080:10.11.50.10:1080 user@ops.example.com` to forward socks5 port 1080 via ops.example.com to 10.11.50.10, now I have the access to 10.11.50.10 directly but I still wish to forward 1080 port (another machine doesn't have the access to this port directly), I tried: `ssh -L 0.0.0.0:1080:10.11.50.10:1080` and this doesn't seem to work...

I guess I can do `ssh -L 0.0.0.0:1080:10.11.50.10:1080 user@127.0.0.1` but it seems a bit counter-productive...

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -L 1080:localhost:1080 user@ops.example.com
```

or

```
ssh -L 1080:127.0.0.1:1080 user@ops.example.com
```

Comment: yeah that's pretty much the same as `ssh -L 0.0.0.0:1080:10.11.50.10:1080 user@127.0.0.1`...

Comment: You're joking, right?